# How to Save Website Pages for Offline access in Firefox/...?

Tags: cyanogenmod, firefox-for-android, offline, oneplus-two, browser

I need to save the website of some shops etc [Power.fi](https://www.power.fi/) because you cannot use LTE data in their shops (metallic halls) but I need to compare their prices to their website prices and others. 
Options of Internet Browsers

1. Firefox because you can install there addons
2. Chrome not because you cannot install addons in Android Chrome
3. ...

Options of the goals

1. It would be nice to save daily catalogs of the websites (whole website).
2. And then when time is in need, just take pages which you need (just a page). (Akhil's answer proposal [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/156169/9897))
3. How to Store 777 single pages to one frontend/client/...?

Firefox plugins under test

- [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/) - does not work in Android Firefox because I cannot even install the app in Android; pressing install just goes infinitely but never installs; restoring the page shows that nothing is installed; I did restart the browser but no difference.
- ...

Chrome (I really would like to find a solution for this as soon as possible Google allows the addons)

- ...

Phone: Oneplus 2
OS: CyanogenMod 13

Comment: The whole website or just a page?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Both methods would be useful. - It would be nice to save daily catalogs of the websites. And then when time is in need, just take pages which you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [HTTrack Website Copier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.httrack.android). Seems to match your needs fully, not tried by me :

> HTTrack is a free software (GPL) offline browser utility, allowing you to download (copy) a website from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting html, images, and other files from the server to your device.
>
> HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online.

**Edit** Tested it now

- All sites do not permit copying - this site doesn't:). For reasons see [FAQ](http://www.httrack.com/html/faq.html#Q0)
- Can be very time consuming when on WiFi. I tried on Amazon India and aborted after 7 minutes . It copied the first page fully, it looks like, but you can set up rules
- I tried on a smaller banking website and it was able to copy fully with three levels of linking

You have to test and see if it works for your sites

Refer [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/9897/masi). Copied the content of LG TV as shown below. Note the download link location in internal storage and the third one shows internal link opened up. Took one minute

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am testing. I use the url: `https://www.power.fi`.

Comment: The site is very big. I let it download 12 hours with 4 Mb/s. The process stop eventually but I see no files about it in Firefox. Maybe, it cannot show partial downloads. I do not know if the download ever finished. Site: power.fi. What do you think?

Comment: Do you see any files in the preferred save location? And what happens when you click *browse mirrored website*

Comment: See the FAQ linked in answer- one could be browser, change browser and two check url

Answer (score 1):

### 2. To Save One Page

You can either use Apps like

- [Pocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro) - 4.5 stars, 10 million downloads
- [Readability](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.readability) - 3.3 stars, 100 thousand downloads
- [Instapaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instapaper.android&hl=en) - 4.2 stars, 100 thousand downloads

These will provide offline readability.

Or you can try to save webpage as PDF from chrome browser/firefox.
As described below:

**Chrome**

1. First, open the page you want to save in Chrome, tap the three-dot menu button in the top-right corner of the screen, then tap *Print*.
2. Once Android has finished creating a preview of the page you want to save, tap the *Save to* drop-down menu at the top of the page.
3. Select *Save to Google Drive* to upload a PDF of the page to your Drive account (make sure you pick the right one if you’re signed in to multiple Google accounts), or tap *Save as PDF* to save the file to your handset’s local storage.

   **Note**: Sure, you could try tapping Share > Google Drive to save a webpage from Chrome to your Drive account, but all you’d be doing is saving a tiny text file with the page’s URL.

**Firefox**

1. On the Web page you want to save, select Menu > Save as PDF.
2. The Android downloader notification appears and notifies you when it is finished.
   To open the PDF, tap Menu > Downloads.
3. Your Downloads screen appears with the PDF listed, tap the PDF to
   open it with the PDF reader installed on your Android phone.

Comment: This answer is about the part (2) of the problem, just storing one page of the website. It is really not the main target here. - -Better would be to store 1000 single pages to some app.

Comment: Please, let us know if you find out how to store many pages of the website to the apps which you mention. I have not found yet anything relevant.